# Prevent public access to staging app in my Heroku pipeline

Tags: heroku

I have a Heroku pipeline with a staging app and a production app. I want to restrict access to the staging app so that features that are being tested (in staging) are not publicly accessible. How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent the public from accessing non production stages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434325/how-do-i-prevent-the-public-from-accessing-non-production-stages)

Comment: I am also looking for the same, any solution which doesn't involve the codebase side. Just a top layer which require authenticating the user and redirect to the staging app url as normal, but none of the Heroku auth addons do so (all of them require touching your app code).