# How do I prevent the public from accessing non production stages?

Tags: heroku

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375386/prevent-public-access-to-staging-app-in-my-heroku-pipeline) a few years ago, but doesn't have an answer. It seems like this should be possible, but I haven't found anything in the Heroku documentation nor elsewhere on the web.

Ideally, I'd like to require a password to non-production stages in my app's pipeline. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375386/prevent-public-access-to-staging-app-in-my-heroku-pipeline) to handle such differences on the codebase side. HTTP authentication is very easy to set up on most servers (only two lines with Express + [express-basic-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth)) and you can turn it on or off depending on whether the app is running in the staging environment or the development environment with [environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#set-up-your-local-environment-variables).